# Proof of poset what it means to cover in terms of quotient

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $P = (N; j)$ be the poset of positive integers ordered by divisibility. Let $a; b$ be in $P$. Describe what it means for $b$ to cover $a$ in terms of the quotient $b=a$. Prove your answer.

Is this asking for a proof about that $b$ is some multiple of $a$? If so i'm unsure how such a proof would look. Any input please. Thank you

Comment: Please comment on why thumbs down for some guidance

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to assume that where you wrote $b=a$, you meant $b/a$ or $b\div a$, as that’s the only thing that makes sense here. If $\langle P,\le\rangle$ is a partial order, and $a,b\in P$, we say that $b$ *covers* $a$ if $a<b$ (i.e., $a\le b$ and $a\ne b$) **and** there is no $x\in P$ such that $a<x<b$. If you like to think in visual terms, $b$ is immediately above $a$ in a Hasse diagram for $P$, with no other elements between them.

You’re supposed to translate this definition to the specific partial order that is the positive integers ordered by divisibility. (I suspect, by the way, that your $(N,j)$ should be $(\Bbb N,\mid)$: $a\mid b$ is the standard notation for ‘$a$ divides $b$’, ‘$b$ is a multiple of $a$’, and that’s the order relation that’s wanted here. If $a,b\in\Bbb N$, and $b$ covers $a$, then first of all $a\mid b$: $b$ is a multiple of $a$. This means that $b/a\in\Bbb N$. But that’s true whenever $a\mid b$, not just when $b$ covers $a$. What kind of integer must the quotient $b/a$ be if $b$ covers $a$? That’s what you’re being asked to figure out. The question is intended to test your understanding of the notion of covering in a partial order and your knowledge of some very basic facts about the positive integers.